# Baskerville Theme - How to use the masonry grid layout on other pages

Tags: themes, masonry

I am using the [Baskerville](https://wordpress.org/themes/baskerville/) theme which looks great but I haven't been able to replicate the Masonry layout on other pages. It works fine on the Home page but there is no template that facilitates this for other pages.

I have tried asking on the offical Baskerville support forum but no one seems to know how to accomplish this.

[Here is a demo of how the Home page looks](http://andersnoren.se/themes/baskerville/)

Comment: I just found a way to accomplish this with Tags or Categories. The theme shows tags or category pages in a masonry layout by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to make a Tags or Category page. The Masonry layout is called on these by default.